# How can I retrieve files from a virus-infected flasdrive?

Tags: virus

I'm pretty sure it's the "New Folder.exe" referenced above.  How can I get my files off without carrying the infection along with them?

Comment: Which *"'New Folder.exe' referenced above"*? What operating system do you run?

Comment: use a linux live CD if you ARE SURE it is a kit doing the mess and not a real virus. then, format the usb stick and place the files back.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided much information, so the only thing I can suggest is to scan it with any antivirus/antimalware software to remove the virus. I highly recommend [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) (there is a free version available).

Other files will remain in the flash drive.